# Pagination not working with Permalink set to /%category%/%postname%/

Tags: wordpress, pagination, permalinks

Really need some help..
I have custom categories where pagination not working.
My Permalink set to /%category%/%postname%/

It always takes me to 404

MyCategory/page/2/

Comment: I feel you need to provide more information before anyone can help you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using Nginx, so all the .htaccess suggestions on wordpress site don't apply. It does work, if you add the category base before category, but I don't want it.

Comment: Did you find out any solutions?

Comment: Did any of these solutions work I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely stumbled upon a common issue when it comes to using category URLs without using the Category Base, which is mandatory and defaults to 'category' if the Category Base field is left empty in the Permalinks Settings.

Please check out these two tickets:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21209
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8905

To make the pagination work your URL should be **category**/MyCategory/page/2/

Alternatively you could use a filter or a plug-in to remove the Category Base from your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set permalinks like this "/blog/%category%/%postname%/"

Answer (score -1):

Try with this filter:

```
add_filter('request', 'remove_category_slug_url');
```

as described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172958/custom-permalink-structure-leads-to-be-404-on-pagination)

```
function remove_category_slug_url($query_string){ 
  if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
    unset($query_string['name']);
  }      
  return $query_string;
}
```

Comment: This does stop the 404 from showing on the second page but it does not actually paginate the posts.